# Python with eclipse import problem

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use eclipse as my IDE for python. Recently I encountered a strange problem. 
A file contains an import from external libraries (such as wx, matplotlib etc.) if I put it inside the src directory, it will run as expected, but in the editor, I get error marks all over the places where I use the imported libraries. The errors say things like "Undefined variable from import".
If I put it in top level of the project, the error marks disappear.


I have added a screenshot of the configuration. I have a feeling that the source of the problem is there, but do not know what to do.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my installation I have several other libraries in the system pythonpath dialog including wx. Try setting the interpreter again in order to reload the libraries or load them manually.

Comment: Tried loading manually, did not help. I found out about #@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore which is a kind of a hack but it works for me.