# matplotlib does not work in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib

I seem to have a problem that is in parts very similar to the one mentioned here:
[Python with eclipse import problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236479/python-with-eclipse-import-problem)

But unfortunatly just in parts otherwise that would have solved mine as well.

I use Eclipse SDK, Version: 3.7.0 with PyDev  101. 
Furthermore I have installed
numpy-1.6.1rc1-win32-superpack-python2.6.exe
and
matplotlib-1.0.1.win32-py2.6.exe
as noted here: 
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html

I have rebuild all the packages and looks the site-packages are listed.

(by the way as you see it is an Python version installed with ArcGIS )

If I test a script for instance a very simple one like:

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib
import pylab as pl
```

I get the following error in Eclipse: 
import matplotlib
import pylab as pl 
from matplotlib.pylab import *
ImportError: No module named pylab

Even though the interpreter for Pydev is pointing to the appropriate version of python and matplotlib is installed properly in there (site-packages) it does not work in Eclipse. In iPython it works perfect.

What still needs to be done to get matplotlib work in Eclipse?

Thanks a lot!

Werner

Comment: Are you sure that pylab is part of matplotlib?

Comment: OMG, I just noticed that you linked to a question I asked.

Comment: Well at least it comes along with matplotlib, is being installed with it and seems to be quite is essential. Anyway, how did you solve the problem with #@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore? Does that work with windows? What exactly did you do?

Comment: Using #@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore did help. You need to put it a the beginning of your py file. This will disable the static analysis of all error, so this is not a good solution, but it is the only one I know.

Answer (score 2):

pylab is in matplotlibs namespace, so this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
```

Comment: or, more succintly, `from matplotlib import pylab`

Comment: @tillsten & @Zhehao Mao 

I still get an error: 
ImportError: cannot import name pylab

Comment: Yes, if I run the same scripts in "iPython" it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I found that turning off interactive move and then calling show worked.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#...your code...

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```